# Conditional module loading in Nuxt.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a module for Google Tag Manager in my Nuxt.js config, like so:

```
modules: [
  [
    '@nuxtjs/google-tag-manager',
    {
      id: 'GTM-XXXXXXX'
    }
  ]
]
```

This is working fine but I am wondering how I can conditionally load this module based on the value of a cookie set by the site?

We have a mechanism by which the user can select certain cookies to accept or deny and a part of that is to block tracking scripts.

Is there any recommended way to do this with modules or scripts loaded via the config? Ideally, it would be possible to then load these should the values within the cookies change in the future as well.

Any help or pointers are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Nuxt modules are only executed during the building process. For example the GTM module allows you to use a function for the `id` and skips the including the whole GTM if `id` is `null` but it won't help you because the `id` function is only executed once and not at run time of the app/site.

I'm currently at the same problem right now and will post the solution as soon as i'm done.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To execute GTM conditionally you have to drop the `@nuxtjs/google-tag-manager` and implement it yourself as a plugin. NUXT docs are really awesome and have you covered on this too. I used [this resource](https://nuxtjs.org/faq/google-analytics/) for implementation and ended up with this code:

```
// app/plugins/gtm.js

import Cookies from 'js-cookie'

const gtmKey = 'GTM-XXXXX' // <- insert your GTM key here

export default () => {
  /*
  ** Only run on client-side and only in production mode
  */
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') return
  /*
  ** Only run if it's not prevented by user
  */
  if (Cookies.get('disable-gtm')) return
  /*
  ** Include Google Tag Manager
  */
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
    (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
    m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  (function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
      new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
    j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
    'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
  })(window,document,'script','dataLayer', gtmKey)
}
```

Basically you allow the user to set a custom cookie (`disable-gtm` in my case) and check this cookie in the `gtm.js` plugin. If it's there and valid, skip everything GTM related.

Comment: Yes, I figured the only way was to avoid the module. It's a shame! Thanks for your insight and help on this.